# What is the use of "Virtual Folders" in the Navigator or Package Explorer of Eclipse / Flash Builder?

Tags: eclipse, virtual, flash-builder, package, directory

These folders can be created similarly to normal folders by right-clicking > New Folder... and then toggling the "Advanced >>" button to show the virtual folder option.

Since the folder isn't located in the file system, just curious as to how exactly are the files stored when I drag them to this virtual folder, and what's the difference / purpose from a normal folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, they have to exist on the file system somewhere :-)

AFAIK linked resources are created for the files under a virtual folder.  That means they point to an absolute path on the filesystem, outside of the workspace.  If you move the file in the filesystem, it gets broken.

See [Virtual folder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/virtualfolders.htm) for a starting point.